# How to allow unrelated histories on git pull with libgit2sharp?

Tags: libgit2sharp

What is libgit2sharp's equivalent to the following git command?

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

I have a scenario where I have to merge a branch from another remote with an unrelated history. When i want to push the merged result to this remote, I'll get a `NonFastForwardException`.

So far I implemented the following code:

```
  using (var repo = new Repository(repoPath))
  {
      Remote remote = repo.Network.Remotes.Add("newRemote", targetRepositoryUrl);
      repo.Branches.Update(repo.Branches["wikiMaster"], b => b.Remote = "newRemote");

      Commands.Pull(repo, sig, pullOptions);

      // Will throw "NonFastForwardException"                                  
      repo.Network.Push(repo.Branches["wikiMaster"], pushOptions);
  }
```

`pullOptions` and `pushOptions` do only contain the credentials.

Comment: You have the same problem if you try to push on the command-line, don't you?  Does force pushing not solve this problem?

Comment: @edward-thomson The same problem occurs on command line but there I can use the --allow-unrelated-histories flag to solve it. Forcing the push solves the problem, but results in loss of the files from one remote.

Comment: Right, I understand now.  There's no support for this in libgit2 / LibGit2Sharp at the moment.  It seems like a reasonable thing to add, but if you need a solution immediately, you could do a `Fetch` and then a manual `MergeTrees` but that's not ideal.  

Comment: Were you ever able to find a work around for this? I'm running into the same road block...